# Subview with clear-color background is repainted with black

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, subviews

I want to cover my main view with subview, which contains help for its content. Because of this, I set background of help subview to ClearColor and I set its alpha to 1.

In header file of main view I have:

```
HelpViewController *helpViewController;
```

In source file of main view is:

```
[self showViewController:helpViewController sender:sender];
```

When this function is invoked, help subview is visible moving over main view. During move subview has transparent background (correct behavior), but at the end of moving subview background turns from transparent to black.

Why my help subview is repainted with black? How to prevent from this?

I have to add, that alpha of subview can't be changed to 0, because elements placed on it will not visible also.

Comment: More code would be useful.

Comment: More code would help like where in your code are you setting your subview to clearColor and when are you invoking your subview?

Comment: Is your HelpViewController view's background colour black by default? You can set a background colour including alpha using `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)`